# Bulkify Opportunity Campaign Source Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

This trigger should populate the Opportunity primary campaign source with the most recent campaign a contact was added to. It works with 1 record but if bulk records are inserted with different contacts, the primary campaign source is only populated on one of the records.

I have also tried without the LIMIT 1 in the query. This populates the campaign source on bulk inserts but if the contact belongs to multiple campaigns it does not populate the most recent campaign. How can I bulkify this so that it works as expected?

```
public static void populateRecentCampaign(List<Opportunity> newOpportunityRecords) {
        Set<Id> conIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity o : newOpportunityRecords) {
            if(o.Related_contact__c != NULL){
                conIds.add(o.Related_contact__c);
            }
        }

        Map<Id, CampaignMember> opps = new Map<Id, CampaignMember>();  
        for(CampaignMember record: [SELECT contactId, campaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE contactId IN :conIds ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1]) {
            if(record != NULL){
                opps.put(record.contactId, record);
            }
        }

        for(Opportunity o: newOpportunityRecords) {
            if(opps.containsKey(o.Related_contact__c)){
                o.campaignId = opps.get(o.Related_contact__c).campaignId;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current strategy is only getting a single `CampaignMember`, regardless of how many Contacts you have:

```
    Map<Id, CampaignMember> opps = new Map<Id, CampaignMember>();  
    for(CampaignMember record: [SELECT contactId, campaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE contactId IN :conIds ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1]) {
        if(record != NULL){
            opps.put(record.contactId, record);
        }
    }
```

That will result in only that single Contact having an associated Campaign via your Map, and your code will take no action on any other Contact.

You can fix this by querying Contact, instead of Campaign, and using a subquery to get the most recent Campaign Member:

```
Map<Id, Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([
    SELECT Id,
        (SELECT CampaignId 
         FROM CampaignMembers 
         ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
         LIMIT 1)
    FROM Contact
    WHERE Id IN :conIds
]);
```

Then, in your latter loop, access via the relationship (making sure to check for an empty array before indexing):

```
    for (Opportunity o : newOpportunityRecords) {
        if (contactMap.containsKey(o.Related_contact__c) && !contactMap.get(o.Related_contact__c).CampaignMembers.isEmpty()) {
            o.CampaignId = contactMap.get(o.Related_contact__c).CampaignMembers[0].CampaignId;
        }
    }
```